# Getting the number of nested shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

[slider]
[img]
[img]
.
.
[img]
[/slider]
Is there a way that I can get the number of nested shortcode in a parent shortcode

Thanks

Comment: are these shortcodes all defined in one plugin or functions.php file?

Comment: In one php file included into functions.php